# In SBT, how do you override compile to run arbitrary code afterwards?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to use SBT to build a project that depends on bytecode enhancement. Basically, I need to run some code after `compile` using the classpath in the current scope (so the command can find the classes to modify), and then make sure that `compile` doesn't run again afterwards to undo the enhancement.

I'm using SBT 0.13.12, if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would want to make a new sbt task and have it depend on compile.  Then use that rather than compile.

```
    lazy val bytecodeEnhancedCompile = taskKey[Unit]("bytecode Enhance")

    bytecodeEnhancedCompile <<= bytecodeEnhancedCompile dependsOn (compile in Compile)

    bytecodeEnhancedCompile  := {
       ....
    }
```

Comment: Attempting this, there's an error at the `:=` operator. It says `value := is not a member of sbt.Def.Initialize[sbt.Task[Unit]]`

Comment: I'm also afraid that running `test` or `console` will re-run `compile`, undoing the bytecode enhancement.

Comment: @TOB fixed syntax.  Perhaps you could change test and console to depend on your new task rather than compile?